# Yii ошибка (The "dataProvider" property cannot be empty.)

Tags: php, yii

Yii ошибка (The "dataProvider" property cannot be empty.)

Пробовал использовать http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView в модулях

```
$da=new CActiveDataProvider('Page');
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$da,
    'itemView'=>'_post',
));
```

лежит в

```
/protected/modules/page/views/admin/page.php
```

Модель Page лежит в

```
/protected/modules/page/models/Page.php
```

и на всякий случай положил сюда ))

```
/protected/models
```

не помогло

---

Вопрос: (Ale_x)
а приведенный вами код где находится? в контроллере или в представлении???

Ответ:
в представлении

Comment: а просто модель Page попробуйте создать в контролеоре и выполнить с ней какиенибуть действия - что напишет?

Comment: щас попробую, можно с тобой как то связаться? есть скайп?

Comment: скап то есть - у меня 3-45 ночи - все спят - поэтому сижу тихо)

Comment: хотя-бы месагами, вот блин там такая же ошибка, хотя такого не должно быть

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: вот я дурак)) я когда создавал
 'itemView'=>'_post', я скачал файл page.php и переименовал, а данные изменить забыл)))
Спасибо больше за уделенное время!

Comment: на будущее в представлении избегай создание объектов моделей - они должны создаватся в контроллерах, а в представлении передаватся для отобржения

Comment: изначально я так и сделал, но решил перейти во views, вдруг заработает))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

файл конфигурации покажи?? там есть автозагрузка файлов вашего модуля?

напиши вот так

```
'import'=>array( 'application.models.*', 
'application.modules.*', 
'application.components.*', ),
```

да кстати в конфигах есть параметр modules? должно тоже быть объявлено

```
 'modules'=>array('page', ...),
```

в общем смотри [тут](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/39377-agile-web-application-development-with-yii11-and-php5/) - там есть пример  кода - он те и нужен
Теперь по русски создать экземпляр CActiveDataProvider - ты должен в контроллере, а потом уже созданный экземпляр передать в представлении через переменную

Comment: это main.php?

'import'=>array(
'application.models.*',
'application.modules.*',
'application.components.*',
),

Comment: там так и написано

Comment: application.models.*  и application.models. - разницу понимаем?

Comment: там со * все, видимо редактор удалил,
в modules прописано

 'modules'=>array(
        'page',
  'gii'=>array(
   'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
   'password'=>'123',
   // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array(),
        ),

 ),

Comment: класс Pege от чего наследуем?

Comment: class Page extends CActiveRecord

Comment: а приведенный вами код где находится? в контроллере или в представлении?

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, вы забыли передать dataProvider. По указанной вами ссылке есть пример, вы все так сделали?

Comment: $da=new CActiveDataProvider('Page');
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$da,
    'itemView'=>'_post',
));
лежит в 
/protected/modules/page/views/admin/page.php

Модель Page лежит в /protected/modules/page/models/Page.php

и на всякий случай положил сюда ))
/protected/models

не помогло

Comment: обновил шапку